# How to declare a dictionary variable inside a swift class?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to define class with a Array and Dictionary as its class variables as follows

```
class MyClass
{
 let myArray : Array = ["one","two"];
 var myDictionary : Dictionary ;

 func myFunc 
 {
   myDictionary = ["key" : myArray];
 }
}
```

But this shows compilation error.

Any help please ?

Comment: the first complier error comes because you left the () after the "myFunc"

Comment: Study compilation errors and warnings. There is usually at least a clue in them, Swift is still to young to have good error messages but still they need to be studied. Then try things. If all else fails there is always the Apple Swift iBook.

Comment: I advice you read up on Swift language: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors:

1: `myArray` needs a type of `[String]`, not `Array`.

2: `myDictionary` also needs a full type: `[String : AnyObject]?`

3: `myFunc` needs an empty parentheses after the function name: `myFunc()`.

4: Not an error but semicolons are not needed at the end of a statement.

```
class MyClass
{
    let myArray : [String] = ["one","two"]
    var myDictionary : [String : AnyObject]?

    func myFunc()
    {
        myDictionary = ["key" : myArray]
    }
}
```